# Send WhatsApp messages automatically with Automate-App

Tags: whatsapp

I want to send a WhatsApp message to a specific contact with the Automate-app. How can do I do this?

This is the link to the app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty late reply. 
You can make use of below blocks and build

- App start block and choose activity class as
  com.whatsapp.ContactPicker
- Use Interact blocks for searching, selecting and messaging
- Extend with Variable for searching contact and for message text

Comment: Starting from "com.whatsapp.ContactPicker" won't work, cause when you click the contact it will go nowhere. You need to start from HomeActivity, then click New Chat, and so on... simulating the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying different ways but many of them fall short of full automation.

currently, I am using blocks to send a message to (unsaved) contact. This skips the contactPicker window.

the flow blocks:
[start flow] --> [view content] --> [interact]

that's it!

in view content, you will need to specify the content uri (change number and msg):
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+966xxxxxxxxx&text=msg

in interact block, specify the (**proceed**) when element appeared.
the (**action**) is click.
and (**XPATH**):

fn:reverse((.//[{("android.widget.ImageButton") = null ? "true()" : "fn:choose(@class,string(@class),name())={"android.widget.ImageButton";xpathEncode}"} and {("com.whatsapp:id/send") = null ? "true()" : "@android:id={"@" ++ ("com.whatsapp:id/send");xpathEncode}"}])[1]/ancestor-or-self::)

that's it.

Comment: I have used this xpath: '//android.widget.ImageButton[@android:id="@com.whatsapp:id/send"]'